# Get sum of a column from three tables and know which table it came from

Tags: mysql, union

I have an odd question. I have three tables all with different information but a few common columns. I want to get a sum from the tables, but I also want to know which table the data came from. I can do the following and get my sum, but how to know which table it came from?

```
select 
    CustName, CustNumber, cost, sum(QUANTITY) as total 
from 
    (select CustName, CustNumber, cost, QUANTITY from table1 
     union all
     select CustName, CustNumber, cost, QUANTITY from table2 
     union all
     select CustName, CustNumber, cost, QUANTITY from table3) x
     
WHERE CustNumber = '894047001034' AND CustName = 'Joseph Smythe'
group by CustName;
```

Comment: Just add the table name as a static column `SELECT 'table1' AS ``tablename`` to each of your individual union select statements.

Comment: Can it come from more than one table?

Comment: Actually yes. The data can come from multiple tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is untested code so some tweaking might be needed.

You could add the tablename as an extra column from your queries and then add the table name to your outer select;

```
select 
    CustName, CustNumber, cost, sum(QUANTITY) as total, table_name
from 
    (select CustName, CustNumber, cost, QUANTITY, "table1" as table_name from table1 
     union all
     select CustName, CustNumber, cost, QUANTITY, "table2" as table_name from table2 
     union all
     select CustName, CustNumber, cost, QUANTITY, "table3" as table_name from table3) x
     
WHERE CustNumber = '894047001034' AND CustName = 'Joseph Smythe'
group by CustName;
```

Comment: I went with this due to the comment made by user2843577. I can't believe I didn't think of adding the additional column and a fixed value. Thanks Folks!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
CustName, CustNumber, cost, sum(QUANTITY) as total,
SUM(CASE WHEN table_name = "table1" THEN QUANTITY ELSE 0 END) as total1,
SUM(CASE WHEN table_name = "table2" THEN QUANTITY ELSE 0 END) as total2,
SUM(CASE WHEN table_name = "table3" THEN QUANTITY ELSE 0 END) as total3
FROM
(
   SELECT CustName, CustNumber, cost, QUANTITY, "table1" as table_name 
   FROM table1 
   union all
   SELECT CustName, CustNumber, cost, QUANTITY, "table2" as table_name 
   FROM table2
   union all
   SELECT CustName, CustNumber, cost, QUANTITY, "table3" as table_name 
) x
WHERE CustNumber = '894047001034' AND CustName = 'Joseph Smythe'
GROUP BY CustName, CustNumber, cost;
```

Or just change the group by of the previous nice suggestion with
GROUP BY CustName, CustNumber, cost, table_name